# Solved / React.js TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined [Tic Tac Toe]

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm trying to build a Tic-Tac-Toe app and I'm getting **TypeError**. *(TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined)*

I think this problem is related to the fact that the "**onClick**" and "**items**" values in Board.js cannot state properly.

Error: components/GameLayout/board.js:7

```
   4 | 
   5 | function Board({ onClick, items }) {
   6 |   const gameSquare = (e) => {
>  7 |     return <BoardSquare value={items[e]} onClick={() => onClick(e)} />
   8 |   }
   9 |   return (
  10 |     <div className="board">
```

Error: components/GameLayout/board.js:11

```
   8 | }
   9 | return (
  10 |   <div className="board">
> 11 |     <div className="board__row">
  12 |       {gameSquare(0)}
  13 |       {gameSquare(1)}
  14 |       {gameSquare(2)}
```

Here is my MainGame component:

```
function MainGame() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(Array(9).fill(null))
  const [isNext, setNext] = useState(true)

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const squares = [...rows]

    if (squares[e] || Winner(rows)) {
      return
    }
    squares[e] = isNext ? "X" : "O"
    setRows(squares)
    setNext(!isNext)
  }

  const winner = Winner(squares)
  let status = winner
    ? `Player ${winner} won!`
    : `The next player is ${isNext ? "X" : "O"} `

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="player__winner">{status}</div>
      <GameBoard onClick={() => handleClick} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default MainGame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze what this error means:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

This means we're doing `something[0]` somewhere, and `something` is `undefined`. You've already identified the line where this is happening:

```
return <BoardSquare value={items[e]} onClick={() => onClick(e)} />
```

Here the *something* is `items`. So where is `items` coming from? Looks like the props of the component:

```
function Board({ onClick, items }) {
  // ...
}
```

So what passes in the `items` prop? Your `MainGame` component:

```
<GameBoard onClick={() => handleClick} />
```

Ah ha! It's not passing an `items` prop. That means it will be `undefined`.

Comment: exactly this! thank you so much. I need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
When calling the Game Board component in Main Game, I forgot to add value props and I was defining the wrong situation in it.

I also forgot to write event in handleclick function.

```
<GameBoard value={rows} onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)} />
```

After these fixes, I added the correct props into the Board component and the problem was solved.

```
function Board({ onClick, value }) {
  const gameSquare = (e) => {
    return <BoardSquare value={value[e]} onClick={() => onClick(e)} />
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can prevent this by making sure items array has actually items , and make sure your passing items prop when your declaring this component in your mean game component

```
function Board({ onClick, items }) {
   if(items.length <1 ) return null    

   const gameSquare = (e) => {
   return <BoardSquare value={items[e]} onClick={() => onClick(e)} />
   }
  return (
     <div className="board">.... </div>
```